# How can I multiply the elements of two nested lists in Python where the sublists are not of equal length?

Tags: python

I have two lists of lists where the sublists can have variable length,
but each list has the same structure. For example:

```
lee =[[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]]

lee2=[[7,8,9], [7,8,9,10]]
```

I want to multiply the corresponding element of each list to give:

```
output=[[7,16,27], [7,16,27,40]]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 2):

One-liner using 2 consecutive `zip` to interleave the lists and then the elements of the lists:

```
lee =[[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]]    
lee2=[[7,8,9], [7,8,9,10]]


output = [[a*b for a,b in zip(*l)] for l in zip(lee,lee2)]
```

result:

```
[[7, 16, 27], [7, 16, 27, 40]]
```

An equivalent method for those unfamiliar with listcomps:

```
output = []
for l1,l2 in zip(lee,lee2):
    for a,b in zip(l1,l2):
        output.append(a*b)
```

Comment: @Lee BTW, this question & answer are being discussed on [SO Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338755/whats-better-a-question-with-no-attempt-or-with-an-unfixable-irrelevant-attemp)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single line with Python, by using list-comrehensions, and the `zip` built-in, which combines elements of one or more iterables in another iterable:

```
output = [[el1 * el2 for el1, el2 in zip(sublist1, sublist2)] for sublist1, sublist2 in zip(lee, lee2)  ]
```

So, `zip` is used here in the outer level to pick each sublist of your inputlists, and on the inner level to pick each element of these sublists.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `operator` module.

```
import operator
output = [map(operator.mul, x, y) for x,y in zip(lee, lee2)]
```

But usually additional imports are not encouraged much.